# Clone gitlab repository Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a repository using visual studio but this message shows up

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've already created an ssh key and copied the pub key

```
 ssh-keygen
 cat /c/Users/Toshiba/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and added it to my gitlab account
when I try to cloneit fromt git bash I get

```
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:eUXGGm1YGsMAS7vkcx6JOJdOGHPem5gQp4taiCfCLB8.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

What should I do?

Comment: `What should I do?` type `yes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing yes is one thing. But it is sensible to *check first* if the fingerprint proposed is indeed the one of the remote GitLab server.

The ones for [`gitlab.com` are shown here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/).
Since what you see (`SHA256:eUXGGm1YGsMAS7vkcx6JOJdOGHPem5gQp4taiCfCLB8`) matches one of those, you can type yes, and update your own `c/Users/Toshiba/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

There is a proposal ([issue 25142](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/25142)) to expose those fingerprints on the server side, implemented with [MR 13850](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/13850) (and [commit f913f7a](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/commit/f913f7a1caa492fdaa06c4ebe0111a080079ff8f)) in GitLab 10.2 (Nov. 2017).